# ADALiOS AcquireToken()

Tags: ios, swift, adal

I've got and tried a number of samples using ADALiOS. ADALiOS keeps changing its implementation as you know. Because I am a beginner of swift, I don't have any idea how to make samples from Internet work.

I tried a version of adal 3.0 (pre release).
as you can see, the below code was copied from one of samples downloaded. Every sample has got a complier errors such as 'missing argument label-policy...' or 'cannot convert ADAuthenticationResult...' in authContext.acquireToken() or acquireTokenwithResource() method regardless of its adal version. anyone can help me?
the error message is about completionBlock:....

thanks

```
authContext.acquireToken(withScopes: [Any](), additionalScopes: [Any](), clientId: clientId, redirectUri: redirectURL, identifier: id!, promptBehavior: prompt, extraQueryParameters: "", completionBlock: <#T##ADAuthenticationCallback!##ADAuthenticationCallback!##(ADAuthenticationResult?) -> Void#>){
        if result.status.value != AD_SUCCEEDED.value {
            // Failed, return error description
            completionHandler(false, result.error.description)
        }
        else {
            // Succeeded, return the acess token
            var token = result.accessToken
            // Initialize the dependency resolver with the logged on context.
            // The dependency resolver is passed to the Outlook library.
            self.dependencyResolver = ADALDependencyResolver(context: authContext, resourceId: self.outlookResource, clientId: self.clientId, redirectUri: self.redirectURL)
            completionHandler(true, token)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I have a working sample of Swift ADAL? None of ADAL swift samples on internet works.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this working using adal 3.0 (pre release). Looks like ADAL API has changed when looking at the examples. I couldn't find acquireTokenwithResource() so I used:

acquireToken(withScopes: additionalScopes: clientId: redirectUri:  identifier:, promptBehavior:)

I think the biggest issue I had was not registering the native app here: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

After I did that and used clientId and redirectURI from apps.dev.microsoft, and also include the correct scope, I was able to authenticate and get back an accessToken.

My acquireToken Looks like this:

```
 func acquireAuthToken(completion: ((AuthenticationResult) -> Void)?) {

        let identity = ADUserIdentifier(id: "Default email address", type: ADUserIdentifierType(rawValue:1))



        self.context.acquireToken(withScopes: ["User.Read"], additionalScopes: nil, clientId: AppData.sharedInstance?.clientId, redirectUri: URL(string: (AppData.sharedInstance?.redirectUriString)!), identifier: identity, promptBehavior: AD_PROMPT_AUTO) {
            (result) in

            if let handler = completion {
                if result!.status == AD_SUCCEEDED {
                    self.accessToken = result!.token

                    handler(AuthenticationResult.Success)
                }
                else {
                    handler(AuthenticationResult.Failure(result!.error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The context is just ADAuthenticationContext(authority: ppData.sharedInstance?.authority, .Authority, error: &error)

HTH